# Erro ao passar valores de array JS para PHP simples

Tags: php, javascript, array

Meu código é esse aqui embaixo:

```
<html>
<body>



<form method="post" action="recebe.php" >
<input type="hidden" id="send_string_array" name="send_string_array" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form> 
</body>
<head>
<script>

//variáveis
var array_produtos = Array([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

var i, array_produtos, string_array;


//varre o array só pra mostrar que tá tudo ok
for (i in array_produtos)
alert(array_produtos[i]);




document.getElementById("send_string_array").value =     array_produtos.join("|");
</script>
</heady>
</html>
```

O código `PHP` que deveria funcionar e mostrar o array é esse:

```
<?php

//transforma a string de itens separados em array
$array_produtos = explode("|", $_POST['send_string_array']);
//mostra o conteúdo do array 
echo $_POST['send_string_array'];

?>
```

O `PHP` está me retornando isso `Array ( [0] => );`, mas deveria conter os valores no array, não?

Qual seria meu erro?

Comment: adailton sua nova edição removeu justamente a linha que eu comentei abaixo sobre ser o problema, com esse código atual permanece o problema?

Comment: é porque voce respondeu enquanto eu estava editando foi mau.

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro está no `javascript`, mas uma observação antes, você está definindo o `array_produtos` duas vezes o que seria desnecessário.

```
var array_produtos = Array([1,2,3,4,5,6]); /* aqui */
var i, array_produtos; /* e aqui */
```

Agora sobre seu erro está nessa linha

```
array_produtos = array_produtos.split("|");
```

O `array` do `javascript` não possui nenhuma função `split` e fora que sua lógica não precisa dessa linha, remova ela e seu programa provavelmente irá funcionar.

Ficando assim o `javascript`:

```
<script>

    //variáveis

    var array_produtos = Array([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
    var i;

    //varre o array só pra mostrar que tá tudo ok
    for (i in array_produtos)
        alert(array_produtos[i]);

    document.getElementById("array_produtos").value =      array_produtos.join("|");
</script>
```

A função `split` que você estava tentado utilizar é quando a variável é `String`, ou seja, você pode utilizar dessa forma:

```
var virouString = array_produtos.join("|");
var virouArrayNovamente = virouString.split("|");
```

Comment: sim mas nao passa pro php, e agora dei uma editada no codigo da uma olhada esta me retornando isso no recebe.php  Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4,5,6 ) onde deveria ficar assim, [1,2,3,4,5,6]); .

Comment: @adailtonmoraes da um `echo $_POST['send_string_array']` no seu `php` pra ver como ele está enviando essa informação

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente editando o codigo com os erros corrigidos.

Comment: @adailtonmoraes Perfeito, se possível marque a resposta como a solução. Boa noite!